# Как происходит общение в MVC с фабриками, загрузчиками?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

В момент инициализации приложения, загрузчик грузит ассеты и по завершению должен наполнить ими фабрику - фабрики. Как он это должен сделать? Что стоит между загрузчиком и фабриками? 
Наполнил фабрики, создал кнопку, при инициализации, она должна получить у фабрики ассетов свой скин. Как она должна это сделать? Кто стоит между кнопкой и фабрикой?

Так же интересно, что такое сервис в составе MVC? Какова его роль, как он общается с фигурантами?

> по завершению уведомляет фабрику -
> фабрика готовит скин

Уведомляет напрямую без участия посредников ( proxy ) ? А кто тогда подготавливает загруженный контент для фабрик ( если я загрузил байты ) ? Или это сами фабрики уже разруливают?

> уведомляет ядро mvc о готовности к
> запуску главного UI - медиатор UI
> элемента

Что такое UI?

И вот ещё один момент - пользователь уже авторизован и находится в меню ( карта ) мира, где выбирает определенный участок. Нажимает на этот участок и загрузчик начинает грузить локацию. Как и кто говорит загрузчику, чтобы он начал грузить? Если у меня закрыто половина локации, то и грузить её всю смысла нет, кто расскажет загрузчику, что грузить нужно только определённые участки локации? Ведь запрос на вид локации должен идти от view, но она не может знать, что мне доступно, а что нет. И на ум приходит только то, что между view и загрузчиком должен быть кто-то ещё...?
Код пока не нужно, если тема разовьётся и возникнет непонимание, то я сам попрошу. Спасибо!

Comment: По сути и загрузчик и фабрики это варианты моделей (singlton-ы естественно) 

- загрузчик запускается при старте всего ядра mvc

- по завершению уведомляет фабрику

- фабрика готовит скин, уведомляет ядро mvc о готовности к запуску главного UI 

- медиатор UI элемента запрашивает скин, и передает его в элемент


пс: использую Robotlegs MVCs, если что могу расписать подробней на основе его, с примерами кода

Comment: - понятие посредника нет в RL, там используются команды, например: нажатие кнопки в ui отправляет событие в ядро mvc, по этому событию стартует команда (контроллер) которая занимается всей цепочкой действий (загрузка, отрисовка и т.д.), все данные необходимые для действия держатся в модели или идут нагрузкой в событии

Comment: Проглядите схему работы RL MVCs:
http://www.robotlegs.org/diagram/

Comment: посредник между ядром MVC и визуальным компонентом это Mediator

UI - user interface, классы обработки графических элементов с которыми взаимодействует пользователь

Comment: А что такое ViewObject ( VO ) ? Посмотрев гугл я так понял, что это UI это класс, который хранит только ссылку на вид. А VO, это объект, который после изменения моделью считывается UI.. Так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути и загрузчик и фабрики это варианты моделей (singlton-ы естественно)

- загрузчик запускается при старте всего ядра mvc
- по завершению уведомляет фабрику
- фабрика готовит скин, уведомляет ядро mvc о готовности к запуску главного UI
- медиатор UI элемента запрашивает скин, и передает его в элемент
- посредник между ядром MVC и визуальным компонентом (UI) это Mediator
- UI - user interface, классы обработки графических элементов с которыми взаимодействует пользователь
- VO - value object, хранилище данных, значений, например UserVO, MapVO, ApplicationVO - выступает именно как хранилище/поставщик/получатель, в нем нет логики ответственной за поведение субъекта, чистое хранилище. За поведение отвечает модель, которая может включать в себя любые VO. Так же VO может включать в себя другие vo.

Проглядите схему работы RL MVCs: http://www.robotlegs.org/diagram/

(собрал как полноценный ответ, кончились коментарии к посту)

Comment: можно в скайпе продолжить про мвс и рл
s w a 5 1 2
без пробелов